# How to set up a django test server when using gunicorn?

Tags: python, django, selenium, gunicorn

I am running an app in django with gunicorn. I am trying to use selenium to test my app but have run into a problem.

I need to create a test server like is done with djangos `LiveServerTestCase` that will work with gunicorn.

Does anyone have any ideas of how i could do this?

note: could also someone confirm me that `LiveServerTestCase` is executed as a thread not a process

Comment: LiveServerTestCase is executed as a thread https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/testcases.py#L1009

Comment: When you run a ``LiveServerTestCase``, Django starts its own WSGI server. Do you really need gunicorn for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes because I need SSL and other production features that the WSGI server Django does not provide.

Answer (score 2):

I've read the code. Looking at `LiveServerTestCase` for inspiration makes sense but trying to cook up something by extending or somehow calling `LiveServerTestCase` is asking for trouble and increased maintenance costs.

A robust way to run which *looks* like what `LiveServerTestCase` does is to create from `unittest.TestCase` a test case class with custom `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` methods.  The `setUpClass` method:

1. Sets up an instance of the Django application with settings appropriate for testing: a database in a location that won't interfere with anything else, logs recorded to the appropriate place and, if emails are sent during normal operations, with emails settings that won't make your sysadmins want to strangle you, etc.

   [In effect, this is a deployment procedure. Since we want to eventually deploy our application, the process above is one which we should develop *anyway*.]
2. Load whatever fixtures are necessary into the database.
3. Starts a Gunicorn instance run this instance of the Django application, using the usual OS commands for this.

The `tearDownClass`:

1. Shuts down the Gunicorn instance, again using normal OS commands.
2. Deletes the database that was created for testing, deletes whatever log files may have been created, etc.

And between the setup and teardown our tests contact the application on the port assigned to Gunicorn and they load more fixtures if needed, etc.

Why not try to use a modified `LiveServerTestCase`?

1. `LiveServerTestCase` includes the entire test setup in one process: the tests, the WSGI server and the Django application. Gunicorn is not designed for operating like this. For one thing, it uses a master process and worker processes.
2. If `LiveServerTestCase` is modified to somehow start the Django app in an external process, then a good deal of the benefits of this class go out the window. `LiveServerTestCase` *relies* on the fact that it can just modifies settings or database connections in its process space and that these modifications will carry over to the Django app, because it lives in the same process. If the app is in a different process, these tricks can't work. Once `LiveServerTestCase` is modified to take care of this, the end result is close to what I've outlined above.

**Additional:** Could someone get Gunicorn and Django to run in the same process?

I'm sure someone *could* glue them together, but consider the following. This would certainly mean changing the *core* code of Gunicorn since Gunicorn is *designed* to use master and worker processes. Then, this person who created the glue would be responsible for keeping this glue up to date when Gunicorn or Django's internals change in such a way that makes the glue break. At the end of the day doing this requires more work than using the method outlined at the start of this answer.

Comment: What if I do want to run Gunicorn and Django on the same process btw? It will help debugging tests more easily.

Comment: Gunicorn meat's goal is to "script Gunicorn from Python". Being able to start Gunicorn programmatically from arbitrary Python code (e.g. ``import gunicorn_starter; gunicorn_start.start_gunicorn(someconfig)``) would fit that goal but would still not allow you to do what *you* want, because it changes nothing to the fact that Gunicorn wants to split itself into master and slave processes.

Comment: Regarding Gunicorn and Django in the same process, I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Off top of my head, you can try to override `LiveServerTestCase.setUpClass` and wind up gunicorn instead of `LiveServerThread`